# Repeated Object Instantiation Inside Loop (Classes and Threads)

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

I am repeatedly calling different methods (subroutines) in different classes inside a loop.  For example, the instantiation goes as follows:

```
Dim parameters(3) As Double = {0, ..., ..., ...}

For i = 1 to 5
  Dim c1 as New Class1(parameters)    '-->change these to threads?
  Dim c2 as New Class2(parameters)
  Dim c3 as New Class3(parameters)
  Dim c4 as New Class4(parameters)
  Dim c5 as New Class4(parameters)
Next i

'In each class I am using: 

Public Class Class1
  Private classparameters(3) as Double
  Sub New(classparameters)
    Dim param_obj(3) as New Object
    param_obj(0)=classparameter(1)
    param_obj(1)=classparameter(2)
    param_obj(2)=classparameter(3)
    Dim t As New Thread(AddressOf Method1)
    t.TrySetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
    t.Start(param_obj)
  End Sub

  Sub Method1(param_obj)
     classparameter(1)=param_obj(0)
     classparameter(2)=param_obj(1)
     classparameter(3)=param_obj(2)

     '...do the math here

  End Sub
End Class
```

However, I would like to consider creation of threads inside the loop, instead of instantiating the objects (classes) and running the methods in each class as a thread.  I think if the class instantiations inside the loop are changed to threads which call the classes, the entire loop could be quickly processed -- and then just wait for all threads to finish.   (fyi, none of the work is sequential, so it can be parsed out).

Is there a more efficient way to organize this?

Comment: What is the maximum version of dotnet that you are allowed to use?

Comment: The maximum version of VS is 2010

Comment: So, you are saying that you could use dotnet 4.5.1, as long as it compiles in VStudio 2010? The reason I ask, is that Microsoft added some really great threading features in .NET 4.0 and even more in 4.5 but if you are only allowed to use 3.5, then there is no point in me suggesting them.

Comment: .NET goes up to version 4.0 for VS 2010.   After that, you need VS 2012 for 4.5.  I am using .NET 4.0 in my current VS 2010 apps.   What are the specific features you are eluding to?   It would be helpful if you listed pseudo-code or flow.   thx, LEP